# 'Embedded nul in string' error when importing csv with fread

Tags: r, data.table, fread

I have a large file (3.5G) that I'm trying to import using `data.table::fread`.

It was originally created from an rpt file that was opened as text and saved as a CSV.

This has worked fine with smaller files (of the same type of data-same columns and all.  This one is just for a longer timeframe and wider reach).

When I try and run

```
mydata <- fread("mycsv.csv")
```

I get the error:

> Error in fread("mycsv.csv") :    embedded nul in string: 'y\0e\0a\0r\0'

What does this mean?

Comment: It looks like UTF-16 (2 or more bytes for every character, almost always 2 bytes). For ASCII, you'll see the ASCII value and then a 0 byte.

Comment: I have had the same problem when loading RData files generated from large data sets. I regenerate the RData and the problem goes away. Seems to be caused when my RAM is maxing out.

Comment: This error also occurs when you try to open an RDS file, inappropriately, with `fread`. Don't ask how I know that.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

We can remove the null terminators on the command line using something like:

```
sed 's/\\0//g' mycsv.csv > mycsv.csv
```

Or as suggested by @marbel, *fread* allows you to pass the *sed* call inside the text. Such as:

```
fread("sed 's/\\0//g' mycsv.csv")
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I'm not exactly sure how to enter that in R.    

One thing I realized, apparently, the error is telling me that the embedded nul is in the string 'year', which is the first word of the first line of the csv (it is the first column heading).

The full error is     

[    Error in fread("allpcts90days1.csv") : 
      embedded nul in string: 'y\0e\0a\0r\0']

Any idea what that's telling me?  When I look at the text in a text editor (TextPad or UltraEdit, since they can handle files of this size), I don't see anything out of the ordinary.

Comment: Your text file has characters that are reserved in ASCII for terminating strings. You need to run that from the linux command line, or if you're on Windows, Google for "how to remove special characters from file windows".

Comment: `fread` allows you to pass the sed call inside the text. Such as: `fread("sed 's/\\0//g' mycsv.csv")`

Comment: It says: `'sed' is not recognized as an internal or external command` and in addition I'm getting an "empty file error"

Comment: I think `sep` might be the argument @RobertKrzyzanowski referred to?

Comment: `sed` is a Unix utility, it won't work on Windows unless you have WSL installed/activated, and if you don't know what `sed` is then you probably haven't activated WSL.  I don't know how to do these things on windows, either; but there should be a way. Robert suggested googling it. Otherwise, installing WSL and running that command on the Linux terminal in the relevant folder should not be too cumbersome. Trying to use it inside the `fread` call will be more difficult.

Answer (score 13):

In this case, you can use `read.csv` with fileEncoding of UTF-16LE rather than `fread`.

```
read.csv("mycsv.csv",fileEncoding="UTF-16LE")
```

Considering your data size, using `read.csv` would take a couple of minutes, but I think it is not a big deal.

Comment: With this size of the data, it can actually close to an hour.

Comment: Based on my exprience, loading 3.5GB data can hardly take more than 15 mins, unless in some very extreme cases.

Comment: @FanWang it depends on column types

Answer (score 5):

You can test this small function:

```
cleanFiles<-function(file,newfile){
  writeLines(iconv(readLines(file,skipNul = TRUE)),newfile)
}
```

It's work for me

Answer (score 4):

A non-technical way to solve this would be, to

1. Open the problematic *.csv*
2. Ctrl+A (Select all)
3. Open new Excel sheet
4. Right click and choose 'Paste as values'
5. Save and use this file in place of original one.

Worked for me, and doesn't take much time.

Answer (score 2):

If you are seeing `NUL (x00)` characters in an ASCII file you can do this:
`data.table::fread(text = readLines(pathIn, skipNul = T), ...)`

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar error, sharing in case others run into the same issue -

```
  embedded nul in string: '\0HA\xa8S\001\0\0\0\xd8@\xa8S\001\0\0\0h@\xa8S\001\0\0\0\xf8?\xa8S\001\0\0\0\x88'
Calls: as.data.table -> fread
```

The cause of this ended up being different column lengths where my first column (headers) were shorter than the rest.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the same error can be caused by **compressed csv** files whose extension doesn't match the compression.

For example, for files written with `fwrite(mydata, "myfile.csv", compress = "gzip")`. Here the option `compress = "gzip"` creates a compressed file that is not a text file as a csv is meant to be.

In this case, the file is compressed but the file extension doesn't show it and `fread` is not able to automatically decompress the file before reading.

You can see if the file is compressed if you do `head myfile.csv` in a UNIX terminal, and the print out is something like ��pG*ʵ��9, instead of what you would expect.

In my case, it was enough to rename the file extension to `.csv.gz` and then read it with `fread`.