# 'Embedded nul in string' when importing large CSV (8 GB) with fread()

Tags: r, csv, sed, data.table, fread

I have a large CSV file (8.1 GB) that I'm trying to wrangle into R. I created the CSV using Python's csvkit `in2csv`, converted from a .txt file,  but somehow the conversion led to null characters showing up in the file. I'm now getting this error when importing:

`Error in fread("file.csv", nrows = 100) : 
  embedded nul in string: 'ÿþr\0e\0c\0d\0_\0z\0i\0p\0c\0'`

I *am* able to import small chunks just fine with `read.csv` though, but that's because it allows for UTF-16 encoding via the `fileEncoding` argument.

```
test <- read.csv("file.csv", nrows=100, fileEncoding="UTF-16LE")
```

I don't dare try to import an 8 GB file with `read.csv`, though.

So I then tried the solution offered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22643372/embedded-nul-in-string-error-when-importing-huge-csv-with-fread), in which you use `sed s/\\0//g file.csv > file2.csv` to pull the nulls out. The command performed just fine and populated a new 8GB CSV file, but I received a nearly-identical error:

`Error in fread("file2.csv", nrows = 100) : 
  embedded nul in string: 'ÿþr\0e\0c\0d\0_\0z\0i\0p\0c\0,\0p\0o\0s\0t\0_\0z\0i`

So, that didn't work. I'm stumped at this point. Considering the size of the file, I can't use `read.csv` on the whole thing, and I'm not sure how to get rid of the nulls in the original CSV. I'm not even sure how the file got encoded as UTF-16. Any suggestions or advice would be greatly appreciated at this point.

Edit: I'm on a Windows machine.

Comment: unless you're never going to get this data feed again thru the same process, it seems like it would be worth-while fixing the data at the source, :-( ...  but that is a different question. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

If you're on linux/mac, try this

```
file <- "file.csv"
tt <- tempfile()  # or tempfile(tmpdir="/dev/shm")
system(paste0("tr < ", file, " -d '\\000' >", tt))
fread(tt)
```

Comment: I'm unfortunately on a Windows (should have specified that earlier, apologies); I do, however, have GnuWin32 installed. That's how I was able to use `sed` before. Is there an equivalent I could run?

Answer (score 0):

A possible option would be to install bash emulator on your machine from http://win-bash.sourceforge.net/ , and remove null terminated strings using Linux tools, as  described, for example, here: [Identifying and removing null characters in UNIX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398393/identifying-and-removing-null-characters-in-unix) or here ['Embedded nul in string' error when importing csv with fread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22643372/embedded-nul-in-string-error-when-importing-huge-csv-with-fread?lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

I think the nonsensical characters happen because the file is compressed. This is what I found when trying to read `vcf.gz` files. `fread` does not seem to support reading compressed files. See e.g. https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/717

`readLines()` and `read.table()` support compressed files, but they are slower.