# Load an .RData file triggers `Error: embedded nul in string:` error

Tags: r, rdata

I am sorry about posting a not reproducible error but the task is with huge and not splittable files (`.RData` ones to be precise).

There are several similar questions, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22643372/embedded-nul-in-string-error-when-importing-huge-csv-with-fread) one or this other [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27069534/embedded-nul-in-string-when-importing-large-csv-8-gb-with-fread) but they all are made for importing `.csv` files which is not my case.

As title, I am trying to load with the `load` function an `.RData` files but this triggers this error:

```
load("trip.Rdata")
Error: embedded nul in string: ''<div id=BOD,socationid="7278708">\0\004\0\t\0\0\0\037<span ->\0\004\0\t\0\0\0.<div id="MAINWRAP" c'
```

I've also tried with `attach` that, by documentation, is able to handle `.RData` files but the error is always the same.

Now, this is awkward because and `.RData` file is the last one from which I would expect an error triggered.

To be honest I do not even know how to ask this question properly because of its awkwardness (I can understand the downvote).

Maybe a solution might rely on the fact that the file is been saved under windows OS and I'm trying to load it on a Mac OS but I can't figure out a way, a possible cause nor a possible solution.

Any help is appreciated.