# R data.table - Error in fread(): embedded nul in string "\0\0\0...\000"

Tags: r, csv, sed, data.table

I am trying to read a CSV file using the `fread` command from the `data.table` package, but I am running into the "embedded nul in string" error.

I am in a Linux OS (Antergos), so any shell script that solves this problem is also welcome.

The CSV file I am trying to read is available in my Dropbox [through this link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/asghw45noffji2n/20170630_Remuneracao.zip?dl=0#) (30MB zipped file).

The reproducible example is quite straightforward:

```
fread("20170630_Remuneracao.csv", encoding = 'Latin-1', dec = ',')

Error in fread("r.csv", encoding = "Latin-1", dec = ",") : 
  embedded nul in string: '\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\000'
```

Approaches tried:

1. `sed 's/\\0//g' 20170630_Remuneracao.csv > 20170630_Remuneracao.csv` as [as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22643518/5420229).
   When I read the file again, it gives the same error as before.
2. `file <- "file.csv"
   tt <- tempfile()  # or tempfile(tmpdir="/dev/shm")
   system(paste0("tr < ", file, " -d '\\000' >", tt))
   fread(tt)`

   From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27069615/5420229).
   The code above solves the null string error, but introduces the new error

   `Expected sep ('    ') but new line or EOF ends field 28 on line 28333 when reading data`

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

**EDIT**
After reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28529499/5420229), I suspected that I could have the same problem. So I opened the file with LibreOffice Calc and saved it again with the appropriate CSV format. In this way **it works**, but since it's not a proper solution, I will leave this question open, hoping for a solution that can be done programatically.

Comment: I suspect your file is corrupted anyway. Ask whoever sent it to you to send it again.

Comment: I suspect the same, @Hong Ooi. Check out my edit. Thanks for your comment!