# Error with fread in R--embedded nul in string: '\0'

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to read a csv file >4GB, However, when I use `fread` command it produces and error

```
library(data.table)
csv1 <- fread("cleaned.csv",sep = ",",colClasses = "character",showProgress = TRUE)
```

**Error:** `embedded nul in string: '\0'`

After some looking I found that you could use `sed` function
such as in this [stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22643372/embedded-nul-in-string-error-when-importing-huge-csv-with-fread)  But I have no clue how to use it in my scenario. Please help!

**UPDATE:**
I have attempted to use the sed function as described below in comments, however, they throw an error.

`sed couldn't flush stdout no space left on device`

**UPDATE2:**
I have solved it with the help of some colleagues.However, I am still looking to automate this activity since I had to repeat the process for each file. Expected Automation would either be from within the R or using a BASH Script. Any Suggestions?

Comment: sed is one of the bash tool which is installed by default in all linux distributions.

Comment: Why don't you try this `fread("sed 's/\\0//g' mycsv.csv")` ?

Comment: Linux- Ubuntu 14.04 using Rstudio server

Comment: then open the terminal and run `sed 's/\\0//g' /src/path/mycsv.csv > /dest/path/mycsv.csv`

Comment: for in-place edit `sed -i 's/\\0//g' /src/path/mycsv.csv`

Comment: possible duplicate of ['Embedded nul in string' error when importing huge csv with fread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22643372/embedded-nul-in-string-error-when-importing-huge-csv-with-fread)

Comment: @AvinashRaj, which terminal linux terminal or do I need to type this command in r terminal ?

Comment: run `sed -i 's/\\0//g' /src/path/mycsv.csv` command in linux terminal.

Comment: @AvinashRaj, this hasnt solved my problem, I have tried multiple ways through multiple functions(readr package, data.table package), even the sed function gives up;Spit out error `sed couldn't flush stdout no space left on device`

Comment: since `sed` doesn't seem to be working, you may want to give `tr` a try.  `tr < file-with-nulls -d '\000' > file-without-nulls`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The csv files were populated with **^@** and they were placed within the blank values, somehow they couldn't be searched or replaced via `sed commands` to solve the problem, I followed the following solution.

In linux, follow to the file directory and use vim command such as,

`vim filename.csv`

`:%s/CTRL+2//g`

`ESC  #TO SWITCH FROM INSERT MODE`

`:wq   # TO SAVE THE FILE`

I had to do this manually for every file. However, I still looking for a way to automate this either within R or using from BASH script.

Comment: Vim scripts (gvim,vim) can be pretty easy to adapt

    `vi -s edit.vim  filename.txt`

where edit.vim contains (the :wq is optional)

    `:%s/CTRL+2//g
    :wq`

you can also use the `:argdo `command to run a command on all files in the argument.