# 'embedded nul in string' with fread (tried all other method still couldn't solve)

Tags: r, vim, sed, data.table, fread

I'm using Mac with RStudio 0.99.489 and R3.2.2. I have a csv file of 1GB, it's not exactly big but still takes around 5 min if I tried to import it with read.csv, and I have a lot files of this size so I tried `fread()`. From reading the previous questions, I learned that this error might be because of missing values on date (a normal entries would be like '03May1995:15:31:50' for the date column, however, where the error occurs, it looks like '05May').

I tried `sed 's/\\0//g' mycsv1.csv > mycsv2.csv` as mentioned in ['Embedded nul in string' error when importing csv with fread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22643372/embedded-nul-in-string-error-when-importing-huge-csv-with-fread), but the same error message still pops up.

`sed -i 's/\\0//g' /src/path/mycsv.csv` simply doesn't work for me, the terminal reports error for this command line (I'm not very familiar with those command lines, so I don't understand the logic behind those)

I tried

```
file <- "file.csv"
tt <- tempfile()  # or tempfile(tmpdir="/dev/shm")
system(paste0("tr < ", file, " -d '\\000' >", tt))
fread(tt)
```

from ['Embedded nul in string' when importing large CSV (8 GB) with fread()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27069534/embedded-nul-in-string-when-importing-large-csv-8-gb-with-fread), I guess it removed the entries where there is a missing value, because when I run `fread(tt)` R says

```
Error in fread(tt) : 
  Expecting 5 cols, but line 5060627 contains text after processing all cols. It is very likely that this is due to one or more fields having embedded sep=',' and/or (unescaped) '\n' characters within unbalanced unescaped quotes.
```

After that, I tried `iconv -f utf-16 -t utf-8 myfile1.csv > myfile2.csv` because it seems like this was caused by some problem with `fread` can't comprehend utf-16, and there might be something wrong with this command line, but it simply gives me a spread sheet with random symbols.

And I saw this

```
vim filename.csv

:%s/CTRL+2//g

ESC  #TO SWITCH FROM INSERT MODE

:wq   # TO SAVE THE FILE
```

from [Error with fread in R--embedded nul in string: '\0'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31701365/error-with-fread-in-r-embedded-nul-in-string-0) but after I typed in `vim filename.csv`, the terminal just read in the whole spreadsheet and I couldn't type in the 2nd command (`:%s/CTRL+2//g`), again, I don't really understand those command lines, so maybe I need to make some adjustment to my situation.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

try

```
sed -i 's/\x0//g' my_file
```

or

```
cat my_file|tr -d '\000' > new_file
```

Comment: for sed -i 's/\x0//g' my_file, terminal returns: sed: 1: "my_file.csv": invalid command code C. For the 2nd one, terminal returns "usage: tr [-Ccsu] string1 string2
       tr [-Ccu] -d string1
       tr [-Ccu] -s string1
       tr [-Ccu] -ds string1 string2" and the same error message of 'embedded nul in string' still shows.

Comment: it's a csv file, I'm using mac and I tried in terminal

Comment: replace "my_file" with the path to your file

Comment: oh! i'm already in the directory where I stored my data, do I still need to put in the path?

Comment: I don't know if the file is in a sub directory..what you can do is drag the file from the display window into the shell where it should be placed

Comment: I tried that, still doesn't work... and for 'cat my_file|tr -d '\000' > new_file', when I use fread(), R gives me the error message that 'Expecting 5 cols, but line 5060627 contains text after processing all cols.' I'm not sure what to do...