# SparkR::collect(df) fails for Japanese characters

Tags: r, csv, apache-spark, sparkr

I have the below csv content

```
123,Out,true,2014-09-30,東芝ライフスタイル　株式会社,null,Web,1234,false,2014-09-21T22:48:28.000+0000
```

I loaded the CSV using spark-csv

```
> df <- read.df(sqlContext, "japanese_char_file.csv", source = "com.databricks.spark.csv", inferSchema = "true")
```

I am trying to convert this SparkR dataframe into R data.frame using

```
temp2bd <- SparkR::collect(df)
```

It gives me the below error

> Error in rawToChar(string) :    embedded nul in string:
>   'q\x9d\xe9\xa4չ\xbf\xa4\xeb\0*\017\032>'

Below is the showDF response

```
'+---+---+----+----------+--------------+----+---+----+-----+--------------------+
| C0| C1|  C2|        C3|            C4|  C5| C6|  C7|   C8|                  C9|
+---+---+----+----------+--------------+----+---+----+-----+--------------------+
|123|Out|true|2014-09-30|q\x9d\xe9\xa4չ\xbf\xa4\xeb\0*\017\032>|null|Web|1234|false|2014-09-21T22:48:...|
+---+---+----+----------+--------------+----+---+----+-----+--------------------+\n'
```

Japanese characters are converted into `q\x9d\xe9\xa4չ\xbf\xa4\xeb\0*\017\032>` which seems to be causing this issue.

I came across ['Embedded nul in string' error when importing csv with fread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22643372/embedded-nul-in-string-error-when-importing-huge-csv-with-fread) and ['Embedded nul in string' error when importing csv with fread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22643372/embedded-nul-in-string-error-when-importing-huge-csv-with-fread). But none worked for me

Do I need to change the way I am reading CSV content? 
Or is there way to run `sed` on Spark dataframe?
Or is it a issue in SparkR?

I am using Spark 1.5.2 in standalone mode

Comment: Both problems you experience (this one, and slow reads) have been resolved in 1.6.0 and questions are duplicates.

Comment: You can try to cherry pick patches from the repo (at least the one for reading) should work just fine in 1.5, but it is a better idea to update.

Comment: yeah I missed for this one. But slow read is not duplicate. I've updated the question

Comment: @zero323 - I will use spark 1.6 to solve this one. Is the slow processing fixed in Spark 1.6 as well?

Comment: Should be. You'll find a link to my PR in the answer.

Comment: @zero323 - This issue has been solved in Spark 1.6. But the other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36085619/any-operations-on-sparkr-dataframe-created-using-r-data-frame-is-very-slow is still valid. It is slow in Spark 1.6.1 as well. For a simple collect(df) took more than 30 secs. I've created an jira ticket https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-14037 for it