# getURL results with embedded nul in string

Tags: r, rcurl

I'm trying to download the below csv with R which results with: `embedded nul in string`

```
library(RCurl)
library(bitops)

URL = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datasciencedojo/IntroToTextAnalyticsWithR/master/spam.csv"
x = getURL(URL)
```

Which results with:

> Error in curlPerform(curl = curl, .opts = opts, .encoding = .encoding)
>   : embedded nul in string: 'v'

Anything I'm missing? How can I make this `getURL` work?

Below is content of `sessionInfo()`

```
> library(RCurl)
> library(bitops)
> 
> URL = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datasciencedojo/IntroToTextAnalyticsWithR/master/spam.csv"
> x = getURL(URL)
Error in curlPerform(curl = curl, .opts = opts, .encoding = .encoding) : 
  embedded nul in string: '<ff><fe>v'
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.2

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] caret_6.0-78    lattice_0.20-35 ggplot2_2.2.1   RCurl_1.95-4.10 bitops_1.0-6   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.14       lubridate_1.7.1    tidyr_0.7.2        class_7.3-14       assertthat_0.2.0  
 [6] rprojroot_1.2      digest_0.6.12      ipred_0.9-6        psych_1.7.8        foreach_1.4.4     
[11] R6_2.2.2           plyr_1.8.4         backports_1.1.1    stats4_3.4.3       evaluate_0.10.1   
[16] rlang_0.1.4        lazyeval_0.2.1     kernlab_0.9-25     rpart_4.1-11       Matrix_1.2-12     
[21] rmarkdown_1.8      labeling_0.3       splines_3.4.3      CVST_0.2-1         ddalpha_1.3.1     
[26] gower_0.1.2        stringr_1.2.0      foreign_0.8-69     munsell_0.4.3      broom_0.4.3       
[31] compiler_3.4.3     pkgconfig_2.0.1    base64enc_0.1-3    mnormt_1.5-5       dimRed_0.1.0      
[36] htmltools_0.3.6    nnet_7.3-12        tidyselect_0.2.3   tibble_1.3.4       prodlim_1.6.1     
[41] DRR_0.0.3          codetools_0.2-15   RcppRoll_0.2.2     withr_2.1.0        dplyr_0.7.4       
[46] MASS_7.3-47        recipes_0.1.2      ModelMetrics_1.1.0 grid_3.4.3         nlme_3.1-131      
[51] jsonlite_1.5       gtable_0.2.0       magrittr_1.5       scales_0.5.0       stringi_1.1.6     
[56] reshape2_1.4.2     bindrcpp_0.2       timeDate_3042.101  robustbase_0.92-8  lava_1.6          
[61] iterators_1.0.9    tools_3.4.3        glue_1.2.0         DEoptimR_1.0-8     purrr_0.2.4       
[66] sfsmisc_1.1-1      parallel_3.4.3     survival_2.41-3    yaml_2.1.15        colorspace_1.3-2  
[71] knitr_1.17         bindr_0.1
```

Comment: Alternative [read.csv(url(URL))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6299220/access-a-url-and-read-data-with-r) works fine.

Comment: Related / Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22643372/embedded-nul-in-string-error-when-importing-csv-with-fread

Comment: Try `read.csv(URL,fileEncoding="UTF-16")`.

Comment: @zx8754 : i would like to point that even `read.csv(url(URL))` return null, also `httr::content(GET(url))` doesn't seems to work, problem still persists

Comment: @parth strange, worked for me: `R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1`

Comment: @zx8754 i'm using a bit ancient `R version 3.1.2 Win 7 64-bit` due to certain restrictions, also `RCurl 1.95-4.8` might be my issue

Comment: @Jas Please provide output of `sessionInfo()`.

Comment: @zx8754 added `sessionInfo()` content to question text.