# Read .rds file from specific git commit

Tags: r, git

(This is not a duplicate of [Reading Rds file from git](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54988152/2804314))

Is there a way of reading an `.rds` file in R (or any other file) from a specific git commit without having to checkout the commit nor create a temporary file (*not* from GitHub, but for example from a bare or non-bare repo saved locally or on a server)?

I tried the following, but not surprisingly it does not work (assuming you have a git repo with some commits and a file `a.rds`):

```
b <- readRDS(system("git show 9358:a.rds"))
> Error in readRDS(system("git show 9358:a.rds")) : 
    invalid 'description' argument
```

Comment: Are you sure that short commit hash (`9358`) is unambiguous?

Comment: It is in this context, because I only have made two commits to the test repo the example is from. But assume I would include 7 digits rather than just 4, or even the whole hash.

Comment: OK, hypothesis ruled out.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem with a text file a few days ago. I solved by saving the file (in the `system` call)  before reading it. I guess in your case it would be something in the lines of:

```r
# Target file output
output_dest <- "~/path/to/output.rds"

# Output stdout to file (in this case 3 commits before HEAD)
system(sprintf('show HEAD~3:your_repo/file.rds > %s', output_dest))

readRDS(output_dest)
```

Comment: The questions asks how to achieve that without having to save the output to a file, but rather by reading the content directly in memory in the R session, like reading from a url would do.